# Convert MySQL JSON argument that is an array to an IN ()

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

SQL Rookie here, I am trying to take a JSON argument into a stored procedure which is a JSON array `[123, 124, 125]` and convert the items to be used in an `IN` expression. I know there is `JSON_EXTRACT` function in SQL but not too familiar with it. This is MySql.

Comment: Is there more to the "json"? I guess this is valid json, but json will usually have more to the structure.

Comment: So its not an actually object, its just a simple array of ID's being passed into the stored procedure, the one I gave was just an example, the issue is it can x number of items in that array '[1,2,3,4]' or '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_table` in a subquery with `in`:

```sql
select t.* 
from tbl t 
where t.some_val in (
    select t1.val 
    from json_table(t.js_arr, '$[*]' columns (val int path '$')) t1
)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z8LCgMpP)

Comment: awesome thanks, I just stumbled across this approach just a little bit ago, going to try it out. Hoping this server is running on a version of MySql that supports it

Comment: I am more trying to do something like SELCT * FROM table where table.userId IN (*extract json array* to work within here), the fiddle was a little confusing. Would something like  SELCT * FROM table where table.userId IN (SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(p_membersArray, '$[*]' columns (val int path '$'))) work?

Comment: @RyanSpeciale Yes, that is the correct idea, although for consistency and clarity you can also include aliasing: `SELCT t.* FROM table t where t.userId IN (SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(t.p_membersArray, '$[*]' columns (val int path '$')))`

Comment: awesome thanks for the help, I just checked the version of mysql the database I am working with is running on and it's 5.7.42. This will deff be helpful in the future though. I am now going down the route of creating a temp table for the ids in the array but my query is referencing the IN () multiple times, and I guess you can reference a temp table multiple times in the same query :(((

Comment: I will mark this answer as complete though because what I asked, you gave me the answer

Comment: any ideas on that let me know lol, I can't use a CTE either my version is too low

Comment: @RyanSpeciale Unfortunately JSON is an inherently difficult structure to work with in any DBMS since a database should be [properly normalized](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221955/postgres-jsonb-column-or-standard-normalized-table). In your case, you might want to redesign/reformat the database so that your single `userId` is associated with each of the values in your JSON array, in their own row. It is probably easiest to write a short Python script to perform that process.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to use `JSON_TABLE`, you should use `MEMBER OF` statement.

JSON_TABLE creates temporary table and then you are querying all over that table to use IN statement. Instead u can use MEMBER OF which is not creating table, instead searches inside json array

Comment: Hi, to make a useful answer, please add a *why*, and preferrably also an example, or some documentation to back you answer u

Comment: Hey can you go into why a little more? I ended up having to do something different due to the version of MySql I am working with does not supper JSON_TABLE. I basically did something really hacky but it worked, I created temp tables but I needed to use the reference more than once in the query so I had to create multiple duplicate temp tables. Like I said not ideal, but it worked.

Comment: @Martijn `JSON_TABLE` creates temporary table and then you are querying all over that table to use `IN` statement. Instead u can use `MEMBER OF` which is not creating table, instead searches inside json array